# Spherical Harmonics Normal

Tags: spherical-harmonics

I'm trying to generate irradiance map with spherical harmonics coefficients.

I have a function SH(l, m, N) that evaluate the basis function for specified band (l, m) and normalized direction N.

The problem is when I project the irradiance map onto a sphere it has seams and wrong direction of lights.

I knew it has to be caused by wrong direction of normal N.

This is how I determine the normal for each cube face.

```
vec2 getUV(in int x, in int y, in int width, in int height) {
    float w = float(width);
    float h = float(height);
    float xx = float(x);
    float yy = float(y);
    return vec2((2.0*xx/(w-1.0))-1.0, (2.0*yy/(h-1.0))-1.0);
}

vec3 getNormal(in vec2 uv) {

    float u = uv.x;
    float v = uv.y;
    vec3 n;

    if (u_side == 0) n = vec3(0,0,1)*u + vec3(0,1,0)*v + vec3(1,0,0); // x+
    if (u_side == 1) n = vec3(0,0,-1)*u + vec3(0,1,0)*v + vec3(-1,0,0); // x-
    if (u_side == 2) n = vec3(1,0,0)*u + vec3(0,0,1)*v + vec3(0,1,0); // y+
    if (u_side == 3) n = vec3(1,0,0)*u + vec3(0,0,-1)*v + vec3(0,-1,0); // y-
    if (u_side == 4) n = vec3(-1,0,0)*u + vec3(0,1,0)*v + vec3(0,0,1); // z+
    if (u_side == 5) n = vec3(1,0,0)*u + vec3(0,1,0)*v + vec3(0,0,-1); // z-

    return normalize(n);
}

void getIrMap() {
    int x = int(gl_FragCoord.x);
    int y = int(gl_FragCoord.y);

    vec2 uv = getUV(x, y, IRMAP_WIDTH, IRMAP_HEIGHT);
    vec3 N = getNormal(uv);
    vec3 E = vec3(0);

    // band factor
    const float bf1 = 2.0 / 3.0;
    const float bf2 = 1.0 / 4.0;

    E += u_coeff0.xyz * SH(0, 0, N);
    E += u_coeff1.xyz * SH(1, -1, N) * bf1;
    E += u_coeff2.xyz * SH(1, 0, N)  * bf1;
    E += u_coeff3.xyz * SH(1, 1, N)  * bf1;
    E += u_coeff4.xyz * SH(2, -2, N) * bf2;
    E += u_coeff5.xyz * SH(2, -1, N) * bf2;
    E += u_coeff6.xyz * SH(2, 0, N)  * bf2;
    E += u_coeff7.xyz * SH(2, 1, N)  * bf2;
    E += u_coeff8.xyz * SH(2, 2, N)  * bf2;

    gl_FragColor = vec4(E, 1.0);
}
```

From my understanding SH() expects direction in spherical xyz coordinate. So I mapped the normal from right hand coordinate system to spherical coordinate with:

```
vec3 n = vec3(N.z, -N.x, N.y);
```

Still weird results.

```
vec3 n = N.zxy;
```

Doesn't work also.

I also tried arranging normal in getNormal() with spherical coordinate in mind. The seams are gone, but the lights still off by about 45 to 90 degrees.

For this test I used a precalculated coefficients of Grace Cathedral from the paper 'An Efficient Representation for Irradiance Environment Maps'.

What gives?

**EDIT**
The SH() take (x, y, z) = (sinθ cos φ, sin θ sin φ, cos θ). With xyz mapped to world -z,-x,y respectively.

Comment: There's no such thing as "spherical xyz coordinate". It's Cartesian coordinates (xyz) or spherical coordinates (theta, phi). Which one does the SH() take? There are both Cartesian and spherical coordinate system versions of SH basis functions.